# (Django) How to use distinct() function?

Tags: python, django, distinct

I've tried all the examples in this document:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

But i couldn't manage to make it work!

The output is look like this:

```
In [1]: from restoranya.psmenu.models import *

In [2]: secenekler = SecenekGruplari.objects.all()

In [3]: print secenekler
[<SecenekGruplari: Acı Seçimi>, <SecenekGruplari: Ek Malzemeler>, <SecenekGruplari: Ekstra>, <SecenekGruplari: Çoklu Seçim>, <SecenekGruplari: Ek Malzemeler>, <SecenekGruplari: Deneme>]

In [4]: secenekler = SecenekGruplari.objects.distinct("isim")

In [5]: print secenekler
[<SecenekGruplari: Acı Seçimi>, <SecenekGruplari: Ek Malzemeler>, <SecenekGruplari: Ekstra>, <SecenekGruplari: Çoklu Seçim>, <SecenekGruplari: Ek Malzemeler>, <SecenekGruplari: Deneme>]

In [6]: secenekler = SecenekGruplari.objects.order_by("isim").distinct("isim")

In [7]: print secenekler
[<SecenekGruplari: Acı Seçimi>, <SecenekGruplari: Çoklu Seçim>, <SecenekGruplari: Deneme>, <SecenekGruplari: Ek Malzemeler>, <SecenekGruplari: Ek Malzemeler>, <SecenekGruplari: Ekstra>]
```

How am I supposed to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Passing a parameter to `distinct` is only supported in Django 1.4+. If you're on a lesser version, you're out of luck. Even then, it's only supported with Postgresql, so if you're using something else, like MySQL. You're out of luck.

Comment: oh sh*t im using 1.3 :( is there another way to do that in Django 1.3?

Comment: `raw`. You can do whatever you want with that.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
secenekler = SecenekGruplari.objects.values("isim").distinct()
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Chris is right, *but* I'd add this:

If you use `.distinct('isim')`, it means that you're selecting all the fields from the database, but the values for the fields that *aren't* in your distinct clause will be unpredictable. You might get different results each time.

If you don't care, because you weren't planning to use the other fields anyway, then it would be better to just not fetch them from the database. Then you can use a normal distinct clause:

```
queryset = SecenekGruplari.objects.only("isim").distinct()
```

Or:

```
isim_values = SecenekGruplari.objects.values_list("isim", flat=True).distinct()
```

Comment: my query needs to be look like this:

    queryset = SecenekGruplari.objects.filter(isim__icontains = request.GET["term"])

is it possible to use distinct() in such a query?

Comment: queryset = SecenekGruplari.objects.filter(isim__icontains = request.GET["term"]).distinct()